# Imageflow does not display with highslide code

Tags: javascript, image, popup, onclick, imageflow

The website I am trying to get it to work on is here:

http://www.kaimeramedia.com/derek/Website/Main_New7.html

The Problem is I can't seem to get the code for highslide to work at the end of the imageflow.js file.

The code is:

```
domReady(function()
{
    var instanceOne = new ImageFlow();
    instanceOne.init({ ImageFlowID:'CGI-Archive',  startID: 3, reflectionPNG: true, onClick: function() { return hs.expand(this, {src: this.getAttribute('longdesc'), outlineType: 'rounded-white', showCredits: false,fadeInOut:true, captionText: this.getAttribute('alt')}); } 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       });
```

ImageFlow works without it, but both are supposed to work together.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is the location of the entire imageflow.js & highslide.js files:

http://www.kaimeramedia.com/derek/Website/imageflow.js

For the highslide.js file swap out imageflow.js for highslide.js

Any help would greatly be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a curly brace missing at the end of your code.

```
domReady(
function()
{
    var instanceOne = new ImageFlow();
    instanceOne.init(
        {
            ImageFlowID     :'CGI-Archive',
            startID         : 3,
            reflectionPNG   : true,
            onClick         : function() {
                return hs.expand(
                    this,
                    {
                        src         : this.getAttribute('longdesc'),
                        outlineType : 'rounded-white',
                        fadeInOut   : true,
                        captionText : this.getAttribute('alt')
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    );
} // <!-- this one is missing in your code
); // EDIT: missing closing bracket here as well
```

another thing that's wrong...
this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var myScript = Asset.javascript(source[, properties]);</script>
```

should probably read:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var myScript = Asset.javascript(source, [properties]);</script>
```

or:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var myScript = Asset.javascript(source, properties);</script>
```

Comment: that seemed to fix part of the problem, but now it just hangs in perpetual loading when you click an image... http://www.kaimeramedia.com/derek/Website/Main_New7.html

Comment: yes, i was afraid that wouldn't solve everything. do you use any debugging tools? chrome has them built in (Ctrl i will bring them up - Cmd i for the mac). firefox has the firebug plugin. On either of them, just check the console. (that's ctrl alt i/ cmd alt i)

Comment: if you do, you will see, that Asset is not defined (and MM_preloadImages)